# What's a suitable lubricant for woodworking clamps?

Tags: tool-maintenance, clamps

I have several different types of clamps all of which I've noticed over time get a little harder to operate, the motion isn't as smooth or easy as I'd like. I'm thinking of F-clamps, "quick" clamps, pipe clamps, etc. Its the metal components which seem to have the issue.

I feel like they should be lubricated but I'm concerned about contaminating my wood workpieces with whatever oil or other substance would go on the clamps. Even something like wax which wouldn't be liquid and drippy could still get transferred by mistake.

Any suggestions for a suitable lubricant or an alternative that might keep the clamps operating smoothly?

Comment: Related, as much of the advice there applies here, as well: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/10768/5572

Comment: Given that many people wax the soles of their planes, wax isn't traditionally someone worries about getting on the surfaces of their work.

Answer (score 1):

Wax is actually widely considered *the* lubricant for this application.

While it's an understandable concern, the small amount that may transfer to wood from incidental contact is a non-issue. Bear in mind the fact that planes, including smoothing planes which may be the last tool to touch a workpiece, often have their soles waxed. Some users even lubricate the soles of their planes with a liquid oil such as 3-in-One or a grease like tallow and with these too there doesn't appear to be any problem.

There's a good video on YouTube about clamp maintenance on Kings Fine Woodworking channel, showing how a good clean and waxing<sup>1</sup> can transform the function of bar-type clamps; the title says it all, [83 - How to Clean Dried Glue from Parallel Clamps and make them slide Better Than New](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrLz3la4rpo).

I want to mention that they also use a silicone lubricant to spray the internals on the moving clamp head, something I'm not sold on. Many woodworkers avoid *all* silicone lubricants in the workshop because of the persistent nature of silicone contamination<sup>1</sup>. Expect decent improvement on any sticky/grabby bar-type clamp if a normal oil or grease are used instead, if you too would prefer not to use a silicone lubricant.

**Spoiler safety note:** the testing in the video shows that acetone and MEK (methyl ethyl ketone) are both suitable solvents to help in cleaning off hardened yellow PVA glue residue. Acetone is significantly less toxic than MEK and is generally much cheaper too, making the choice between them easy IMO<sup>2</sup> (they make the same recommendation).

---

<sup>1</sup> Silicone is infamous for how it interferes with finish application (on new pieces and in refinishing) and in how difficult it is to get rid of every trace completely.

<sup>2</sup> This isn't to say don't buy MEK at all (where it's still legal to buy retail....... sorry Californians, people in other places with a Nanny State), there are other applications where it is the ideal solvent choice. But take suitable safety precautions to protect yourself when using.

Comment: The push to ban solvents in California isn't a "nanny" issue (i.e. keeping end-users safe from dangerous chemicals.)  It is a smog issue.  Several of the big cities in California are surrounded by mountains (LA/Riverside in particular, but also Sacramento and Fresno) and the smog will just sit in the basins and linger forever.  Every ounce of solvent that is sold eventually evaporates and contributes to this.  That said, I make sure to keep enough mineral spirits and denatured alcohol on hand to keep me supplied for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, California is infamous for being a Nanny State, so I'm comfortable in labelling it as such :-) whether it's relevant to the question of their ban on solvents or not. But elsewhere the bans and heavy restrictions on certain chemicals can be just silly. There are maybe a dozen things you can buy in almost every hardware store in the US that are banned from sale to consumers over here, it's just bonkers.

Comment: "Nanny state" says the guy who lives in England... :) The People's Republik of Californiastan is trying to out-do you guys, and sadly, because it's easier to have one product line to sell throughout the US (witness: car industry in the 80s), they are setting de facto policy for the whole US. It's rather annoying. :(

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, re, England, yeah I know, tell me about it! Here in the UK we haven't been able to get a decent finish stripper in years because of it -_-

Comment: that was @FreeMan but I know what you mean.  The strippers here still work but not when you get down to the 50+ year old layers...

Comment: You know, @SaSSafraS1232, if all I'd read was your comment about 50 year old strippers... :D

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, oops yes, thanks!

Comment: @FreeMan, yeah sorry about mis-tagging my reply there! Re. the Comment I just left under your recent Answer about casework, the rules of conduct forbid me from actually saying what I wanted to say there. But seriously you wasted your time, OP in that case always knows better \*rolleyes*

Comment: @Graphus oh he will love the answer I just posted then...!

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, yes indeedy! I gave it a +1 FWIW, but I betcha it'll be too soft for the OP. Or there'll be some other reason trotted out for it not being suitable. Assuming he doesn't just abandon the Q...... another of his SOPs :-/

Comment: Roy Underhill, star of The Woodwright on PBS, wrote about the joys of mutton tallow as a tool lubricant in Popular Woodworking Magazine in the August 2010.

Comment: @JohnCanon, yup, and similar refined animal fats like lard can also be used. I find them way too greasy for my taste (for this purpose specifically — too prone to attracting dust as with all 'wet' lubricants/anti-rust coatings). Plus tallow etc. aren't as readily available to most as good ol' paste wax, and if necessary it can even be made at home with little effort.